# Esp8266 programming

Tags: arduino, esp8266, serial-communication

I am working on an Arduino and esp8266 project and I am facing a problem that after uploading following code nothing is showing on serial monitor. I am using USB connector to power up the Arduino then connected Esp8266 with it by connecting all 6 wires. I bypass the Arduino by connecting reset with ground. There is no error while uploading code but its showing nothing. Tried connecting esp8266 TX with Arduino RX and esp RX with Arduino TX. And TX with TX and RX with RX also but still hard luck. Baud rate is same 115200 port is also correct but still not working. Kindly help me to figure it out ! Thanks
PS: I attached the schematic, kindly check that.[image: Schematic]

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial) { delay(100); }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: and do you pull  io 0 HIGH for normal run?

Comment: No, GPIO 0 is low

Comment: then the esp8266 goes into bootloader mode at reset

Comment: should I connect it to high ?

Comment: at least disconnect it from ground

Comment: Tried, nothing happened

Comment: the pull-up io 0 over a resistor

Comment: I didn't get you..

Comment: sorry. a typo. then pull-up io 0 over a resistor